# Adding Special Characters to an XML file that is stored in an XML DB?

Tags: xml, special-characters, exist-db

I am using eXist xml database now.Normally, I just store regular xml files in it. I found that if I try to put some special entities like "lambda" into the xml file, I will always get the following error:

```
"The entity lambda was referenced, but not declared".
```

I tried all possible ways to add entities definition in various config files in eXist db, but still not effect at all. However, the &quot,&amp,&lt are working.

Wonder if any body has similar experience of adding more special character to xml file? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never tried to use lambda in my xml file, but I think that eXist will accept the normal html escape.
So for lambda, it will be `&#923;` and `&#955;`. I found it from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda) and tried it in my client and works fine.
However, I don't know how to reappear your error message so just hope it's the answer your want.

Comment: thanks, that is helpful. So instead of using "&lambda", we should be using "&#923"?

Comment: yes, the eXist doesn't support "&lambda;" but "&#923"(uppercase) or "&#955"(lowercase)

Comment: thank you for help, I will use your solution. Just out of curiosity, do you think we could modify some files in eXist by adding customized character like "&lambda" in, to make eXist recognize them?

Comment: no, I don't know if there's any way to do this. Maybe you can suggest it on their website. :D